# Express.js piping request to php built-in server on localhost results in ECONNREFUSED

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, express, reverse-proxy

I am building a simple website using npm for development, and it is hosted with a provider with php support.

The only functionality that uses php is contact form to send email. the rest is simple html and javascript.

I use a simple php server in development started with `php -S localhost:8000` to test a simple php email script and again in dev I reverse proxy requests for `email.php` to this php server locally.

Node app is on port 3000 and php server is on port 8000. The problem is I get connection refused error with the following express server configuration when request goes through *localhost:3000/email.php*:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var express = require('express');
var app = express(),
  request= require('request'),
  port = +(process.env.PORT || 3000);


app.set('case sensitive routing', false);

app.post( '/email.php', function( req, res ){
  req.pipe( request({
    url: 'http://localhost:8000/email.php',
    qs: req.query,
    method: req.method
  }, function(error){
    if (error.code === 'ECONNREFUSED'){
      console.error('Refused connection');
    } else {
      throw error;
    }
  })).pipe( res );
});


 // other request handlers here

app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log('listening');
});
```

Php server is definitely up and serving all the pages on port 8000, which I can browse with the browser. I test it with *curl* and it seems to be handling the request just fine when posted directly to localhost:8000 using curl.

Not sure why I get this error, scratching my head, can't think of any reason.

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Is your express server running on the same server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out what it was, d'oh! Well I am gonna post the answer in case someone else stumbles upon this.

PHP is to blame it seems; Checking the sockets listening a port using `ss -ltn` ( I am on Linux, this might not work for you) I realised php server is listening IPv6 only. Relevant output as follows:

```
State      Recv-Q Send-Q                                              Local Address:Port                                                             Peer Address:Port                
LISTEN     0      128                                                           ::1:8000
```

With the relevant search I found the answer on web server documentation page under user notes posted by a user. See the post [here](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php#120449). The solution is to use 127.0.0.1 rather than localhost:

> As it turned out, if you started the php server with  "php -S
>   localhost:80"  the server will be started with ipv6 support only!
>
> To access it via ipv4, you need to change the start up command like
>   so: "php -S 127.0.0.1:80" which starts server in ipv4 mode only.

Comment: You're a lifesaver. Thank you.